# No horizontal scrollbar for prismjs code highlights with bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [prismjs](http://prismjs.com/) for code highlighting in my web app, but the horizontal scrollbar in the prismjs box for long lines of code is never enabled. It's because I am also using twitter bootstrap 3 (works fine if I remove the bootstrap css), but I can't figure out how to fix it to work with bootstrap.

Here is the code:

```
<table id="views" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Map</th>
        <th>Reduce</th>
        <th>Emit mapping</th>
        <th>Collections</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for view in views.views %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{{ url_for('view.get_view', name=view.name) }}">{{ view.name }}</a></td>
            <td><pre><code class="language-python">{{ view.map }}</code></pre></td>
            <td>{{ view.reduce }}</td>
            <td>{{ view.emit_mapping }}</td>
            <td>{{ view.collections }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The prismjs-specific code is the following line:

```
<pre><code class="language-python">{{ view.map }}</code></pre>
```

How can I get the horizontal scrollbar? Setting a fixed width for the pre element in css does not resolve the issue.

[jsfiddle reproducing the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/aFfPa/2/).

Thank you,

Comment: jsfiddle of rendered HTML and CSS please.

Comment: @JeremyCook, here: http://jsfiddle.net/aFfPa/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it with the following css code:

```
pre {
  overflow: auto;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

And then I just put the code in a container like this:

```
<td><div class="container"><pre><code class="language-python">{{ view.map }}</code></pre></div></td>
```

The problem was that bootstrap overrides the white-space and word-wrap by default.